Toast with Infinite Duration Persists on Navigation When Using Browser Back Button
When using ShadCN's toast component with an infinite duration, the toast is set to only be dismissible through user interaction (by clicking a close button). However, an issue arises when users navigate to a previous page using the browser's back button: the toast persists on the new page, even though it may no longer be relevant to the current view. This requires the user to manually close the toast, which can disrupt the experience. Ideally, the toast should automatically close or reset upon a route change to ensure it only displays relevant messages for the current context.
this is how i use the toast in my code
toast({
  variant: "error",
  title: "Login Error",
  description: errorMessage,
  duration: Infinity,
  action: (
    <ToastAction altText="Close" onClick={() => setIsBlockingError(false)}>
      Close
    </ToastAction>
  ),
});

I tried using the useNavigate hook to detect route changes in my toast hook and dismiss the toast when the page changes. However, this didn’t quite work.
Anyone have an idea on how to achieve this?
this is my default use toast hook from shadcn ui
"use client"

// Inspired by react-hot-toast library
import * as React from "react"

import type {
  ToastActionElement,
  ToastProps,
} from "@/components/ui/toast"

const TOAST_LIMIT = 1
const TOAST_REMOVE_DELAY = 1000000

type ToasterToast = ToastProps & {
  id: string
  title?: React.ReactNode
  description?: React.ReactNode
  action?: ToastActionElement
}

const actionTypes = {
  ADD_TOAST: "ADD_TOAST",
  UPDATE_TOAST: "UPDATE_TOAST",
  DISMISS_TOAST: "DISMISS_TOAST",
  REMOVE_TOAST: "REMOVE_TOAST",
} as const

let count = 0

function genId() {
  count = (count + 1) % Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER
  return count.toString()
}

type ActionType = typeof actionTypes

type Action =
  | {
      type: ActionType["ADD_TOAST"]
      toast: ToasterToast
    }
  | {
      type: ActionType["UPDATE_TOAST"]
      toast: Partial<ToasterToast>
    }
  | {
      type: ActionType["DISMISS_TOAST"]
      toastId?: ToasterToast["id"]
    }
  | {
      type: ActionType["REMOVE_TOAST"]
      toastId?: ToasterToast["id"]
    }

interface State {
  toasts: ToasterToast[]
}

const toastTimeouts = new Map<string, ReturnType<typeof setTimeout>>()

const addToRemoveQueue = (toastId: string) => {
  if (toastTimeouts.has(toastId)) {
    return
  }

  const timeout = setTimeout(() => {
    toastTimeouts.delete(toastId)
    dispatch({
      type: "REMOVE_TOAST",
      toastId: toastId,
    })
  }, TOAST_REMOVE_DELAY)

  toastTimeouts.set(toastId, timeout)
}

export const reducer = (state: State, action: Action): State => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case "ADD_TOAST":
      return {
        ...state,
        toasts: [action.toast, ...state.toasts].slice(0, TOAST_LIMIT),
      }

    case "UPDATE_TOAST":
      return {
        ...state,
        toasts: state.toasts.map((t) =>
          t.id === action.toast.id ? { ...t, ...action.toast } : t
        ),
      }

    case "DISMISS_TOAST": {
      const { toastId } = action

      // ! Side effects ! - This could be extracted into a dismissToast() action,
      // but I'll keep it here for simplicity
      if (toastId) {
        addToRemoveQueue(toastId)
      } else {
        state.toasts.forEach((toast) => {
          addToRemoveQueue(toast.id)
        })
      }

      return {
        ...state,
        toasts: state.toasts.map((t) =>
          t.id === toastId || toastId === undefined
            ? {
                ...t,
                open: false,
              }
            : t
        ),
      }
    }
    case "REMOVE_TOAST":
      if (action.toastId === undefined) {
        return {
          ...state,
          toasts: [],
        }
      }
      return {
        ...state,
        toasts: state.toasts.filter((t) => t.id !== action.toastId),
      }
  }
}

const listeners: Array<(state: State) => void> = []

let memoryState: State = { toasts: [] }

function dispatch(action: Action) {
  memoryState = reducer(memoryState, action)
  listeners.forEach((listener) => {
    listener(memoryState)
  })
}

type Toast = Omit<ToasterToast, "id">

function toast({ ...props }: Toast) {
  const id = genId()

  const update = (props: ToasterToast) =>
    dispatch({
      type: "UPDATE_TOAST",
      toast: { ...props, id },
    })
  const dismiss = () => dispatch({ type: "DISMISS_TOAST", toastId: id })

  dispatch({
    type: "ADD_TOAST",
    toast: {
      ...props,
      id,
      open: true,
      onOpenChange: (open) => {
        if (!open) dismiss()
      },
    },
  })

  return {
    id: id,
    dismiss,
    update,
  }
}

function useToast() {
  const [state, setState] = React.useState<State>(memoryState)

  React.useEffect(() => {
    listeners.push(setState)
    return () => {
      const index = listeners.indexOf(setState)
      if (index > -1) {
        listeners.splice(index, 1)
      }
    }
  }, [state])

  return {
    ...state,
    toast,
    dismiss: (toastId?: string) => dispatch({ type: "DISMISS_TOAST", toastId }),
  }
}

export { useToast, toast }

